# Image not loading in python raspbian

Tags: python, image

I'm getting an error when trying to load an image in python (pygame)
the code i'm using is something someone else wrote, and proven to be working.
I'm using an Orange pi, running raspbian for this, and when trying to load an image it throws an error.

I've checked the path to the image multiple times, have tried different images and different image formats but it all comes back to the same error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame
import sys
import time
from pygame.locals import *

import OPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setboard(GPIO.PCPCPLUS)
GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BOARD)
# set GPIO output pin
IP = 26

GPIO.setup(IP,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(IP,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

# picture display size
width = 1280
height = 720

# number of pictures
pictures = 1

# picture names
pic_names = ['screen1.jpg']

# USB stick name
usb_name = "/root/pi/"


windowSurfaceObj = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Instructies')

x= 0
while True:

  imagefile = usb_name + pic_names[x]
  image = pygame.image.load(imagefile)
  image = pygame.transform.scale(image,(width,height))
  windowSurfaceObj.blit(image,(0,0))
  pygame.display.update()

  if GPIO.input(IP)== False:
     x +=1
     if x > pictures - 1:
        x = 0
  for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

     elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
        # press N for normal screen
        if event.key == K_n:
           windowSurfaceObj = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
           windowSurfaceObj.blit(image,(0,0))
           pygame.display.update()
        # press F for fullscreen
        if event.key == K_f:
           windowSurfaceObj = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
           windowSurfaceObj.blit(image,(0,0))
           pygame.display.update()
        # press X to EXIT
        if event.key == K_x:
           pygame.quit()
```

The code should open a window, show the image and when multiple images are defined it should go to the next image when a button is clicked using gpio pins. The last part is untested on my part, as I want to make sure the image is even loading before continueing, but it should work.
The images will be located in /root/pi/ which is the path I entered, also tried different paths (which shouldn't work) but all fails.

EDIT: I did some more digging to try and fix it, nothing works so far, but at least some more info!
I used os.getcwd() to see what folder the script is running from, the folder is /root
I copied the image to the root folder, so it should load the image when using image.load(screen1.jpg) but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

So in my case I found out what the issue was, couldn't find the answer anywhere just had to keep digging.
For anyone else having the same issue where all your paths are defined correctly, and you're sure the image is in the right folder, etc. try this:
add this to the top of the file:
import os
print(listdir('path'))   (path in my case was /root)

This will print all files in the folder.
Oddly the image didn't show up with the extension, just showed up as screen1
So I thought, let's try this in the code without the extension, and weirdly this worked for me!

If anyone has an explanation for this, please comment!